# State which JavaScript library is missing

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes Stack Exchange sites will complain that an external library is failing to load:

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

That's good, as far as it goes. But if the code can detect *that* a library is missing, presumably it knows *which* library is missing?

Why not state which library, from which specific URL, is missing so that those with the inclination can have that information to use in troubleshooting?

> Stack Overflow requires the external JavaScript library [foo.js](https://example.org/foo.js), which is blocked or failed to load.

Comment: Since all the libraries are on a CDN, if one fails they all will (apart from the stub loader), because 99.99% of the time the CDN is blocked.

Comment: Sometimes you can use info from the browsers dev tools to track it down.